# R: How to get the names of objects passed to a function?

Tags: r, ggplot2, names

I'm trying to make a function for obtain different versions of several plots. Often, I have to make reports for several analyses carried on, and my co-workers need different versions of the plots (dark background, light background, etc.) to use them in different presentations, papers, etc.

My try is:

```
PlotVariants <- function(plotList){
  #' Función para generar diferentes formatos de gráficas para su
  #' visualización. Requiere que las gráficas se hayan hecho con ggplot2
  #' Function to generate several graphs formats to better visualization.
  #' It requires that graphs had been done in ggplot2.
  #' plotList: lista con todas las gráficas que queremos modificar
  #' plotList: list with all graphs to modify

  library(ggplot2)
  library(ggthemes)
  Formatting.plots <- function(x){
    name.plot <- deparse(substitute(x))
    plt <- x + theme_bw(base_size=11) +
      theme(panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
            panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
            legend.background=element_blank())    
    ggsave(filename=paste('Figures/',name.plot,'_bw.pdf', sep=''),
           plot=plt)

    plt <- x + theme_solarized(base_size=11) +
      theme(panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
            panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
            legend.background=element_blank()) 
    ggsave(filename=paste('Figures/',name.plot,'_solarized.pdf', sep=''),
           plot=plt)

    plt <- x + theme_solarized(light=FALSE,base_size=11) +
      theme(panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
            panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
            legend.background=element_blank())
    ggsave(filename=paste('Figures/',name.plot,'_solarized_dark.pdf', sep=''),
           plot=plt)
  }
  lapply(plotList, Formatting.plots)
  return('DONE')
}
```

Function works, as different figures are saved in 'Figures/' folder of the project, but the names of the plots in the plotList are transformed to X[1L] to X[[nL]] (where n is the number of plots in the list), resulting in Figures/X[[1L]]_bw.pdf for example (see code below):

```
# Libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)

# Some foo.data and two foo.plots to use as example
foo.x <- rnorm(10)
foo.y <- rnorm(10)
foo.df <- data.frame(x=foo.x,y=y)
foo_plot_1 <- ggplot(foo.df,aes(x=x,y=y))+
                   geom_point()
foo_plot_2 <- ggplot(foo.df,aes(x=x,y=y))+
                   geom_line()

# Creating the foo.list to use with the function
foo.list.plots <- list(foo_plot_1,foo_plot_2)

# Calling the function
PlotVariants(foo.list.plots)

# Expected content of the Figures/ folder:
dir('Figures/')

foo_plot_1_bw.pdf
foo_plot_1_solarized.pdf
foo_plot_1_solarized_dark.pdf
foo_plot_2_bw.pdf
foo_plot_2_solarized.pdf
foo_plot_2_solarized_dark.pdf

# Actual content of the Figures/ folder:
dir('Figures/')

X[[1L]]_bw.pdf
X[[1L]]_solarized.pdf
X[[1L]]_solarized_dark.pdf
X[[2L]]_bw.pdf
X[[2L]]_solarized.pdf
X[[2L]]_solarized_dark.pdf
```

I've been reading and searching for an answer to the problem, but i was unable to find one. I hope someone can guide me to obtain the correct names, if possible.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem really lies in the `lapply` at the end.  You'd need to rewrite you function in a way that takes a data set and names (to be modular).  Then you can pass the data and names via `mapply`.  There are other approaches as well.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how i missed that question. It worked perfectly after a little tweaking.

Comment: I don't know if remove the question as duplicate, or left the question to point to the answer.